# #WPF Change image on mouseOver Button

Tags: c#, wpf, styles

I'm trying to change the image inside the button in the stackpanel. 
When the button detects the mouse, I want the image to change. Is it possible ?

Thank you

My button :

```
   <Button Background="Transparent" Height="17" Width="17" BorderBrush="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0 0 6 0" Click="Button_Click" ToolTip="Copier les informations dans le Clipboard" Grid.Column="4" Style="{StaticResource hover2}">
                <StackPanel Height="17" Width="17">
                    <Image Source="Resources/copyPaste.png" Height="17" Width="17" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>
```

my style apply :

```
<Style x:Key="hover2" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>       
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Border Name="border" 
                        BorderThickness="0"                         
                        BorderBrush="Transparent"                          
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can:

```
<Grid.Resources>
          <Style x:Key="hover2" TargetType="Button">
              <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
              <Setter Property="Template">
                  <Setter.Value>
                      <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                <ContentPresenter.Content>
                                    <Border Name="border" 
                                          BorderThickness="0"                         
                                          BorderBrush="Transparent"                          
                                          Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                        <Image x:Name="ButtonImage1" Source="Resources/copyPaste.png" Height="17" Width="17" />
                                    </Border>
                                </ContentPresenter.Content>
                            </ContentPresenter>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                              <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                  <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
                                    <Setter TargetName="ButtonImage1" Property="Source" Value="Resources/hoverImage.png" />
                                </Trigger>
                          </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                      </ControlTemplate>
                  </Setter.Value>
              </Setter>
          </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>
```

See I place your controls inside the content presenter then named the image then in your control template triggers you can access the image thru its name then assign the source of it.

`Button`

```
 <Button
           x:Name="Button1"
           Background="Transparent"
           Height="17"
           Width="17"
           BorderBrush="Transparent"
           HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0 0 6 0" ToolTip="Copier les informations dans le Clipboard" Grid.Column="4" Style="{StaticResource hover2}"/>
```